# How to set up Kotlin's byte code version in Gradle project to Java 8?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

In Kotlin project, what is a proper Gradle script to make sure my classes will be compiled to byte code ver 52 (Java 8)?

For some reason my classes are compiled as ver 50 (Java 6) even though I set up source and target compatibility. At least this is what Idea shows me when I open file from directory `build/classes/...` after building the project.

My current set up looks like this.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.0.5-2'
        springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

// I also tried this and it hasn't helped
//sourceCompatibility = 1.8
//targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${kotlinVersion}")
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit')
}

dependencyManagement { imports { mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Camden.SR2" } }
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

As Mark pointed out on Debop's answer, you have to configure both `compileKotlin` and `compileTestKotlin`. You can do it without duplication this way:

```groovy
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }
}
```

For a pure Kotlin project, I don't think the options `sourceCompatibility` and `targetCompatibility` do anything, so you may be able to remove them.

Ref: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#compiler-options

Comment: I would do this:

`org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile::class.java`

Comment: FYI, don't use `all` use `configureEach` this is the prefered way for task avoidance and will speed up your configuration phase on larger projects

Comment: Update for Kotlin 1.8, this is now the preferred syntax (kotlinOptions is [deprecated](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#exposing-kotlin-compiler-options-as-gradle-lazy-properties)):

`tasks.withType(KotlinCompile).configureEach { compilerOptions.jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_1_8) }`

Answer (score 78):

In case someone uses gradle with **kotlin-dsl** instead of groovy:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

// compile bytecode to java 8 (default is java 6)
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: The same solution in one line:
`tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> { kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8" }`

Answer (score 42):

Kotlin 1.1 in Gradle. in console you have error about `inline` (your installed compiler is 1.0.x)
If run gradle task in IntelliJ IDEA, your code compiled by kotlin 1.1 compiler

```
compileKotlin {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        apiVersion = "1.1"
        languageVersion = "1.1"
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you may need to duplicate this in a compileTestKotlin block to also apply this config to test code.  If I'm wrong about this, though, I'd like to know about it and why.

Comment: You are correct. That's because this is configuring only the `compileKotlin` task. It's better to configure all tasks with type `KotlinCompile` to ensure that any existing, or added, tasks that compile Kotlin are configured to use the desired Java version.

Answer (score 19):

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

// JVM target applied to all Kotlin tasks across all subprojects

// Kotlin DSL
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
}

//Groovy
tasks.withType(KotlinCompile) {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Answer (score 11):

In your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
    tasks {
        val java = "11"

        compileKotlin { 
           kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = java }
           sourceCompatibility = java
        }
    }
```

Or like this:

```
tasks {
    withType<KotlinCompile> { kotlinOptions { jvmTarget = "11" } }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Kotlin 1.0 always produces Java 6 class files. Kotlin 1.1 will support generating Java 8 class files by passing `-jvm-target 1.8` to the compiler. See

https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2016/07/first-glimpse-of-kotlin-1-1-coroutines-type-aliases-and-more/

for a discussion of Java 7/8 support.

Answer (score 7):

Since gradle 6.7 there is so called **java toolchain support** in gradle which I find easiest to use.

It allows you to configure the JDK to use for this project and will even download the required version if needed.

All you need is a compatible JRE to start gradle and this block in your gradle build file:

**kotlin dsl**

```
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain {
        // for gradle kotlin plugin < 1.7:
        (this as JavaToolchainSpec).languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
        // for gradle kotlin plugin >= 1.7:
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}
```

**groovy dsl**

```
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(17))
    }
}
```

**Note:** This will update the java compiler settings as well, so you don't need anything else in your build.gradle.kts

Read more about this in the docs:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#set-custom-jdk-home

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html

Also note that you need to pull in a plugin to download the JDK if you want to use this feature as well.

Comment: As per: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#gradle-java-toolchains-support, there is even shorter syntax:
`kotlin { jvmToolchain(17) }`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone like me who use maven to build mixed code of kotlin and java in intellij , you need to set

```
<kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>1.8</kotlin.compiler.jvmTarget>
```

because maven build doesn't respect jvmTarget set in project setting.

Comment: In which file should this be set?

Comment: In you Pom.xml, under the properties tag.

Answer (score 1):

thx for seanf's anwser ,but if your DSL kotlin is 1.3.0:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile::class.java).all {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Comment: `kotlin-dsl` was already answered with better syntax at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45994990/627727

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting an error like this:
`Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option`.

Then, you can simply add the following in `build.gradle` (in Groovy) in order to tell kotlin to build using 1.8.

```
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all of the above and I was still getting warnings for `compileTestKotlin`.
This is what cleared all of them in the root `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile).all {
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = 17
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

New syntax for `konlin-dsl`:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

java {
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_20
}


kotlin {
    compilerOptions {
       jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_20)
    }
}
```