# Configure Gradle for Kotlin with Java 1.7

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

Ok, so I'm new to Gradle and Kotlin and I am having a hard time understanding how things glue together here...

I need to configure a project that should run on Java 7 (client limitations -_-) and I want to use Kotlin with it.

Right now I have the following `build.gradle` file that is working but I want to ask a few things that I couldn't find anywhere else:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.15.RELEASE'
        kotlin_version = '1.1.1'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.springkotlin'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('com.onelogin:java-saml:2.3.0')
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
    testCompile group: 'javax.inject', name: 'javax.inject', version: '1'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.6"
    }
}
```

Now the questions:

1. I have tried using `kotlin_version = '1.2.70'` (released last few days!) and I got the error `KotlinPluginWrapper : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`. I'm guessing then this is due to Kotlin 1.2.X only being able to "compile" (is that the word?) with Java 8+. Is that right? Is `1.1.1` the right version to use here or is there a way to use `1.2.70` that would work with Java 7? Will I be missing a lot of stuff for using it?
2. I want to understand the 3 kotlin stuff I had to setup on the script. Correct me please:

   - `kotlin-gradle-plugin`: Is used to define which version of Kotlin I will be using(?)
   - `apply plugin: 'kotlin'`: As far as I know from Gradle, this should add tasks to work with Kotlin but running `gradle tasks` I didn't see anything different... So what is it really for?
   - `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`: I'm guessing this is Kotlin lib of functions, classes, etc. What I don't understand though is the difference between `stdlib` and `stdlib-jdk7`. The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html) says it contains "addition extension functions". But which ones? Also, should I define a version for this guy? Or does it automatically picks up the `kotlin-gradle-plugin` version?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the *compiler* of the Kotlin language requires JDK 8 to run. A *project* compiled with Kotlin can target any Java starting from Java 6.

A recipe to setup Gradle build of a project that runs on Java 7 is following:

- run Gradle with Java 8 or later
- for all Kotlin compile tasks

  - specify `jvmTarget = "1.6"` in `kotlinOptions`
  - specify path to JDK 7 in `jdkHome` in `kotlinOptions`
- if your project contains java code specify `sourceCompatibility`, `targetCompatibility` convention properties of the Java plugin
- specify the following `options` of all java compile tasks:

  - `isFork = true`
  - `forkOptions.javaHome = "<path to JDK 7>"`
- for all Test tasks specify `executable` as `"<path to JDK 7>/bin/java"`

The full sample:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

def JDK_7 = System.getenv("JDK_7") // or some other way to get path to JDK 7 installation

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile) {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.6"
        jdkHome = JDK_7
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.javaHome = file(JDK_7)
}

test {
    executable = "$JDK_7/bin/java"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ilya! If I understood right, like this I can use lastest version of `kotlin-gradle-plugin`, right? I just need to run it with Java 8
Will do some testing! Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoMenighin Yes, you can and should use the latest Kotlin Gradle plugin version with such setup.

Comment: I think I made it. Being new to gradle I didnt knew the power of `targetCompatibility` and etc. Basically I set them to `1.7` and the kotlin target to `1.6`. Checking the `.class`es generated, I can see they are compatible with Java 7. My point is: I didnt set the JDK7 anywhere. I used the JDK8 to compile to Java 7. I also didnt set up that fork option of yours. It seems to be working everything... Do you think its necessery to set the jdkHome to java 7?

Comment: Yes, you should set `jdkHome`, otherwise you risk using JDK 8 APIs accidentally and that will crash in runtime.

Comment: Thanks! I will do it just in case. But I have tested, and trying to use `stream` already give me a markup error on IntelliJ

Answer (score 2):

1. Kotlin can target either Java 6 or Java 8 and I don't think this has changed. However, it is quite likely that the default has changed from Java 6 to Java 8, so try as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42276271/3755692):

   ```
   compileKotlin {
       sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
       targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6

       kotlinOptions {
           jvmTarget = "1.6"
           apiVersion = "1.2"
           languageVersion = "1.2"
       }
   }
   ```
2. The version of `kotlin-gradle-plugin` is the version of the Kotlin compiler used to compile your code. The version of the stdlib is the version of your runtime library. It is highly recommended to use the same version here.
3. The `apply plugin: kotlin` adds some tasks under the hood - just continue using the java tasks like `gradle assemble`, `gradle build` and `gradle run` as they will invoke the kotlin specific tasks
4. `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` adds very little value - unless you use features of the java library that were introduced in java 7 **and** that have extensions from Kotlin's stdlib, you'll be fine to just use the default stdlib (which targets Java 6 and is a dependency of `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` anyways).

Comment: Thanks for the answer @msrd0. I did what you said on step 1 and for my surprise it seems now I am using Kotlin 1.2 (at least the `arrayOf` method is working now). So just to get things right: I am now using Kotlin Compiler 1.1.1 (`kotlin-gradle-plugin`) to compile kotlin 1.2 language to Java 6. Is that it? If so, what would be different if I could use `kotlin-gradle-plugin 1.2.70`? Maybe optimized code?

Comment: Im asking all of this because I want to know what kind of problem I may run into for using `kotlin-gradle-plugin 1.1.1`... Thanks again!