# Does OkHttp 4.0.0 require JVM target 1.8?

Tags: android, kotlin, jvm, okhttp

Is OkHttp 4.0.0 intentionally incompatible with jvm target 1.6? Upgrading from OkHttp 3.12.0 to 4.0.0 I run into the following build failure.

> Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is
>   being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target'
>   option

On further inspection I found the root cause to be the `Interceptor` interface having a static method (function inside companion object). The [upgrade guide](https://square.github.io/okhttp/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/) does not mention this backward incompatibility leading me to believe it's unintentional.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found a [blog post](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/okhttp-3-13-requires-android-5-818bb78d07ce) with some explanations. Since OkHttp 3.13.1 JVM target 1.8 is required. The suggested change is:

```
android {
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
  ...
}
```

I found that it still fails. Adding one more instruction finally fixes the build.

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

Comment: Btw, the way to use jvmTarget is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113268/how-to-set-up-kotlins-byte-code-version-in-gradle-project-to-java-8

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest solution for this is to do the following:

Groovy:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

Kotlin (kts):

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```