# Set Kotlin's Java API version with Gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to compile a Kotlin project with gradle so it can be run with java 1.8. I have jdk14 installed on my machine.

I want compile errors if I accidentally use java 11 APIs like Optional.orElseThrow()

I've tried:

```
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

This will correctly throw errors if **Java** coded uses the new APIs, however, Kotlin code will happily continue to use them

I've also tried as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41113268/2881646):

```
compileKotlin {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

compileTestKotlin {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

But that seems to make no difference

Comment: I "solved" it by installing jdk8 and running gradle with that. Would be nice to not need an old jdk installed.