# How to replace the deprecated kotlinOptions in a java-library & kotlin module?

Tags: android, kotlin, groovy, deprecated, java-module

Within my Android application project I am using the following [Gradle (Groovy) configuration](https://github.com/EventFahrplan/EventFahrplan/blob/dd9132cda0d4fd89935291ec0edcbb732b641fef/engelsystem/build.gradle) for a library module:

```
// build.gradle

apply plugin: "java-library"
apply plugin: "kotlin"

dependencies {
    api Libs.engelsystem
    implementation(Libs.retrofit) {
        exclude group: "com.squareup.okio", module: "okio"
    }

    testImplementation Libs.junit
    testImplementation Libs.kotlinCoroutinesTest
    testImplementation Libs.mockitoKotlin
    testImplementation Libs.okhttpMockWebServer
    testImplementation Libs.retrofitConverterMoshi
    testImplementation Libs.truth
}

sourceCompatibility = Config.compatibleJavaVersion
targetCompatibility = Config.compatibleJavaVersion

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = Config.compatibleJavaVersion // is set to JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        freeCompilerArgs += [
                "-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
        ]
    }
}
```

Android Studio Giraffe / Lint notifies me that `kotlinOptions` is **deprecated**.

[image: Screenshot of the quick tip]

There is no quick fix to apply. How can I replace the notation correctly? It seems there is a different syntax for this kind of library module. There is no deprecation warning in a `com.android.library` module nor in a `com.android.application` module. Both use the `kotlin-android` plugin if that is an important difference.

## Potential answer

> ... consider them as non-officially deprecated ...

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27301/Expose-compiler-flags-via-Gradle-lazy-properties#focus=Comments-27-6565858.0-0

## Related

- [JetBrains/kotlin: Update Gradle plugin api to use compiler options (19.09.2022)](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/a3ac5b91f62b095f6dac40837e4636980f26ebde)
- [JetBrains/YouTrack/KT-27301: Expose compiler flags via Gradle lazy properties](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-27301)
- [How to set up Kotlin's byte code version in Gradle project to Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113268/how-to-set-up-kotlins-byte-code-version-in-gradle-project-to-java-8)

Comment: I just cloned the git repo and built the whole project. I should admit I am not getting any such deprecation warning stated by you in the build.gradle file for the module engelsystem. Although, I had to change the jvmTarget value to "11" instead of `Config.compatibleJavaVersion` because otherwise it was failing to compile this module: engelsystem/src/test/kotlin/info/metadude/android/eventfahrplan/engelsystem/EngelsystemNetworkRepositoryTest.kt:81:32 Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 11 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.8. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option

Comment: same way. It doesn't give an error.

Comment: @Jay I am using Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1. Canary 10. Lint might take a moment. It shows the warning for me once I let Gradle sync. Wrt. the `jvmTarget` - it should be fine - only Android Studio doesn't get along with the `buildSrc` folder - hence the warning there. Did you checkout the `master` branch?

Comment: @Jay **Correction:** I do not get the `jvmTarget` error in `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch  1` when the JDK 11 is selected in the IDE settings. In `Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1. Canary 10` I get the described error although JDK 11 is selected. I might have to republish an artifact of the Engelsystem library to fix this. Still checking. - Wrt. the **deprecation warning**: it is visible in both IDE versions.

Comment: `Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch  2` also builds fine for me.

Comment: `Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 RC 1` also builds fine for me. The [new `#GRADLE_LOCAL_JAVA_HOME` macro](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#jdk-macro) might be related to the error in `Iguana` although the macro was already introduced in `Hedgehog`.

Comment: It's not really deprecated yet, but apparently there is some particular configuration that can cause the deprecation warning to appear. This happened in a couple of my projects. I'm not using freeCompilerArgs, so I just went ahead and switched to the new `compilerOptions` for specifying `jvmTarget`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I haven't manage to migrate to AGP 8.x.x and Gradle 8.x.x. Does `compilerOptions` work before? Can you please provide the configuration example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile tasks have the new `compilerOptions` input, which is similar to the existing `kotlinOptions` but uses [Property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Property.html) from the `Gradle` Properties API as the return type.

Here is your updated code:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinJvmCompile


tasks.withType(KotlinJvmCompile).configureEach {
  compilerOptions {
    jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_11)
    freeCompilerArgs.add("-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn")
  }
}
```

References:

- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-compiler-options.html
- https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#exposing-kotlin-compiler-options-as-gradle-lazy-properties

Comment: we have updated the app with new gradle version with 8.4 and AGP with 8.3.0.,am facing the following issue with this > Could not create task of type 'KotlinCompile'.
         > class java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.lang.Boolean and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
   > KotlinJvmAndroidCompilation with name 'betaDebugAndroidTest' not found.
can you suggest how can i solve this.. even i tried with above suggested solution and other , but still am getting the same issue.